# Cannot Draw a Composite Piecewise Function

Tags: plotting

I have defined two functions: g, which is a piecewise function, and h, which is the composition of g.

```
g = Piecewise[{{2 x, x < 1/2}, {2*(1 - x), x > 1/2}}]
h = g@*g@*g@x
```

I want to plot two functions. I used the command `Plot[g, {x, 0, 1}]` and `Plot[h, {x, 0, 1}]`. The first one was successful while the second one failed.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- `g` should be a `pure function` when we use `Composition`, `@*`.

```
Clear[g,h];
g = Function[{x}, Piecewise[{{2 x, x < 1/2}, {2*(1 - x), x > 1/2}}]];
h = g@*g@*g;
Plot[h@x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

- The same as the `Nest`.

```
Plot[Nest[g, x, 3], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The arguments to functions should be explicit rather than implied.

```
g[x_] = Piecewise[{{2 x, x < 1/2}, {2*(1 - x), x > 1/2}}];
```

Use [`PiecewiseExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) to produce a single [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
h[x_] = g@*g@*g@x // PiecewiseExpand // Simplify
```

[image]

```
Plot[h@x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Bob Hanlon's idea with the help of `Fold`:

```
g[x_] = Piecewise[{{2 x, x < 1/2}, {2*(1 - x), x > 1/2}}];

Plot[Simplify@Fold[g@# &, ConstantArray[g[x], 3]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: your answer is helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

Your problems started with defining expressions that were not Mathematica [Function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)s.

Your problem with $h$ is that Mathematica [Plot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) expects its first argument to be an ***expression*** of the plotting variable and not a bare function. Mathematica needs to know where to *put* the plotting variable.

```mma
g = Function[x, Piecewise[{{2*x, x < 1/2}, 
     {2*(1 - x), x >= 1/2}}]]
h = Function[x, (g @* g @* g)[x]]
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[h[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

The outputs:

```mma
Function[x, Piecewise[{{2*x, x < 1/2}, {2*(1 - x), x >= 1/2}}]]
Function[x, (g @* g @* g)[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, I may have missed something.

Comment: thanks for your answer